# How to rectify overriding Result in ArrayList Using Java?

Tags: java, mysql

How to rectify overriding Result in ArrayList?
In my DataBase have one table

```
Course

code    cname
 j1      java
 f1      flex
```

I'm getting these values in java program using bellow code.

```
------
------
ArrayList<CourseBean> al=new ArrayList<CourseBean>();
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select cname from Course where code IN ('j1','f1')");

while(rs.next())
{
  CourseBean cb=new CourseBean();//Hear CourseBean have setter getter methods of cname                   

  cb.setCname(rs.getString("cname");
  al.add(cb);

}
```

But i'm getting ANS :

```
flex
flex
```

But Actually ANS  :

```
java
flex
```

Any solution?

Comment: Are you sure the methods and data members in CourseBean are not `static`?

Comment: Yes my CourseBean class is like Bean class in that only

Comment: There is no semi colon after CourseBean initialization....Does this code snippet even compile? Provide us your actual code.

Comment: Sorry... now i'm giving actual code

Comment: like someone said, can you also post the code where you are retrieving the ArrayList elements?

Comment: Actually i'm retrieving values using Flex so i'm using Auto generation code. I think no problem in flex side only proble in Java For example if we give in the sql Query like... IN ('j1')...then it is giving ...java... only.

Comment: if you give more values like.... IN ('j1','f1').... then it is override the First value ...java... place of ...flex... and second value ...flex... coming correctly..

Comment: Your code as shown above should populate the list correctly, ASSUMING the database looks the way you have shown it.  You will have to add debug print statements or step through this with a debugger to find out what's going wrong,